# Nearest record and corresponding distance between each record in two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, distance

Suppose I have two `DataFrame`s: `XA` and `XB`, for example each with 3 rows and 2 columns:

```
import pandas as pd

XA = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1': [1, 2, 3],
    'x2': [4, 5, 6]
})

XB = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1': [8, 7, 6],
    'x2': [5, 4, 3]
})
```

For each record in `XA`, I want to find the nearest record (e.g. based on Euclidean distance) in `XB`, and also the corresponding distance. For example this might return a `DataFrame` indexed on `id_A`, and with columns for `id_B` and `distance`.

How can I do this most efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to compute the full distance matrix, then `melt` it and aggregate using `nsmallest`, which returns the index along with the value:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def nearest_record(XA, XB):
    """Get the nearest record in XA for each record in XB.

    Args:
        XA: DataFrame. Each record is matched against the nearest in XB.
        XB: DataFrame.

    Returns:
        DataFrame with columns for id_A (from XA), id_B (from XB), and dist.
        Each id_A maps to a single id_B, which is the nearest record from XB.
    """
    dist = pd.DataFrame(cdist(XA, XB)).reset_index().melt('index')
    dist.columns = ['id_A', 'id_B', 'dist']
    # id_B is sometimes returned as an object.
    dist['id_B'] = dist.id_B.astype(int)
    dist.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    nearest = dist.groupby('id_A').dist.nsmallest(1).reset_index()
    return nearest.set_index('level_1').join(dist.id_B).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This shows that `id_B` 2 is the nearest record to each of the three records in `XA`:

```
nearest_record(XA, XB)

 id_A       dist id_B
0   0   5.099020    2
1   1   4.472136    2
2   2   4.242641    2
```

However, since this involves computing the full distance matrix, it will be slow or fail when `XA` and `XB` are large. An alternative that computes the nearest for each row would likely be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54660816/1840471) to avoid a full distance matrix, you can find the nearest record and distance for each row in `XA` (`nearest_record1()`), then call `apply` to run through it on every row (`nearest_record()`). This cuts run time by ~85% in a [test](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18pRjKi44PZNEZfYVR7XAwiCHQ4ixUs9l).

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def nearest_record1(XA1, XB):
    """Get the nearest record between XA1 and XB.

    Args:
        XA: Series.
        XB: DataFrame.

    Returns:
        DataFrame with columns for id_B (from XB) and dist.
    """
    dist = cdist(XA1.values.reshape(1, -1), XB)[0]
    return pd.Series({'dist': np.amin(dist), 'id_B': np.argmin(dist)})

def nearest_record(XA, XB):
    """Get the nearest record in XA for each record in XB.

    Args:
        XA: DataFrame. Each record is matched against the nearest in XB.
        XB: DataFrame.

    Returns:
        DataFrame with columns for id_A (from XA), id_B (from XB), and dist.
        Each id_A maps to a single id_B, which is the nearest record from XB.
    """
    res = XA.apply(lambda x: nearest_record1(x, XB), axis=1)
    res['id_A'] = XA.index
    # id_B is sometimes returned as an object.
    res['id_B'] = res.id_B.astype(int)
    # Reorder columns.
    return res[['id_A', 'id_B', 'dist']]
```

This also returns the correct result:

```
nearest_record(XA, XB)
    id_A    id_B        dist
0      0       2    5.099020
1      1       2    4.472136
2      2       2    4.242641
```